# Как поправить блок?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, веб-программирование

Добрый день!

Помогите решить проблему с календарем. При некоторых разрешения, меньше десктопа, он подлезет под блок выше или ниже. Я не могу понять какой z-index нужно увеличьте.

Выглядит глюк так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылка на сайт(блок внизу на главной):centurymedicaldental.com

Пробовал исправить так:

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget, .dropdown-menu, .datepicker {
    z-index: 2147483647 !important;
}
```

Помогите исправить баг.

Comment: Пробовали position:absolute и менять положение?

Comment: так у него и так абсолют

Comment: поделитесь кодом, я постараюсь помочь.

Comment: Есть другое решение, думал может что-то быстро кому-то в голову придет. Спасибо.